# While create adset then I got error 'Invalid parameter'

Tags: facebook-ads-api

I am using FB Ads API, and successfully created campaigns and get the ID from Facebook. In the next step to create adset with below code then got error.

// Call create using an array of parameters.

```
$data = array(
    AdSetFields::NAME => 'My AdSet',
    AdSetFields::BID_TYPE => 'CPC',
    AdSetFields::BID_INFO => array(
    'CLICKS' => 500,
    ),
    AdSetFields::CAMPAIGN_STATUS => AdSet::STATUS_ACTIVE,
    AdSetFields::DAILY_BUDGET => 200,
    AdSetFields::CAMPAIGN_GROUP_ID => $campaign_id,
    AdSetFields::TARGETING => array(
    'geo_locations' => array(
    'countries' => array(
    'US',
    'GB',
    ),
    ),
    ),
    );
    $ad_set = new AdSet(null, $account->id);
    $ad_set->create($data);
```

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException' with message 'Invalid parameter' in /www/facebookads/src/FacebookAds/Http/Exception/RequestException.php:129

Answer (score 1):

I got solution for this error, 
**DAILY_BUDGET** - increased upto 4000 then it is converted to INR 40.00 
then I  created adset successfully